# Convert and replace time to seconds in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I have a large number of cells that contain time duration in the form:

41m 9s

How do I convert the duration into seconds, and then replace the old value of the cell with the converted value ?

I attempted using the following formula for the minutes part:

```
=LEFT(CELL, FIND("m", J8,1) - 1)*60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i imagine something like this should work. change the A1 references to where ever your data is

```
=(LEFT(A1, FIND("m", A1,1) - 1)*60)+(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1,1)),FIND("s",A1,1)-FIND(" ",A1,1)-1))
```